# Recovering git files from different branch

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I really need help with something I did on Github. Let me start from the beginning. I started working on a react-native app and kept pushing my changes on the master branch. Then a few days ago due to a problem in my code, I ran "git checkout " so I successfully moved back to that commit. After that, I created many files and did a lot of changes (kept committing too) but when I saw my Github repo there was no change. When I came back to VS Code I realized I am not on the master branch so I checked out and moved to the master branch. And in doing so all my files got deleted and all the changes discarded.

Here is my git reflog:'

```
411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a (HEAD -> 14214ff, origin/master, master, 411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a, 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2) HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2 to master
14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2 HEAD@{17}: commit: Few changes
10eb5e22a766c4bda2c1e2fa309dd804886d5263 HEAD@{18}: commit: Few more done
9d5adbd5b2628452c3ca9319133e72bc0c069f1f HEAD@{19}: commit: Few screen added
562fbe672444877a5cc619b34b8957d7ac238053 HEAD@{20}: commit: Added a few more
411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a (HEAD -> 14214ff, origin/master, master, 411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a, 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2) HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from master to 411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a
411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a (HEAD -> 14214ff, origin/master, master, 411e0e5ef541715d6352813286681a508116870a, 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2) HEAD@{22}: commit: Added appointment details
c5e2cf982aa615b76c02e7903f390cc1d5782d09 HEAD@{23}: commit: Added 2 more
f3eb288dcc7327718b5c80f4108473500c13b071 HEAD@{24}: commit: Added 4 screens more and updating styles
```

What I want is to move to this point: `14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2 HEAD@{17}: commit: Few changes`

I have tried checking out to that point but no changes occur. Can anyone help me recover those files?

Comment: You mean you ran `git checkout 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2` but you do not see commit `14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2` as the current commit now? What *is* the commit now, and what *was* the output from `git checkout 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2`?

Comment: This is what i get after running git checkout ```14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2
warning: refname '14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git switch -c $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"````

Comment: OK, this means you created a *branch or tag* named `14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2`. You should rename or delete that, so that the ambiguity goes away. Then you can be sure that `git checkout 14214ff3254b340100ee0f3b9ac272ce8710dcc2` will result in the expected detached-HEAD setup. (Use `git branch` and `git tag` with no arguments to see the branch or tag name. Then use `git branch -m`, if it's a branch name, to rename it, or `git branch -d` or `git tag -d` to delete a branch or tag.)